# Opening a Windows Explorer Window in C++

Tags: c++, encryption

I recently wrote the following code for a school project; with my objective to make a basic encryption program. Currently to encrypt a file with this program, the file name needs to be known and typed in to the console manually including the file extension. To improve the program's user-friendliness, I wanted to implement a function to open a Windows file explorer window so the user can select the file they want to encrypt. After much searching on the internet, I was not able to find any way to implement this into my code. So my question is, does this functionality exist in the C++ library, and if so how could I implement it into my code.

```
#include    <iostream>  
#include    <fstream>       
#include    <stdio.h>      
#include    <math.h>
using namespace std;

#define     ENCRYPTION_FORMULA      (int) Byte * 25  
#define     DECRYPTION_FORMULA      (int) Byte / 25 

int Encrypt (char * FILENAME, char * NEW_FILENAME)
{
std::ifstream inFile;   
std::ofstream outFile;                 
char Byte;          
inFile.open(FILENAME, ios::in | ios::binary);       
outFile.open(NEW_FILENAME, ios::out | ios::binary); 

    while(!inFile.eof())
{
    char NewByte;
    Byte = inFile.get();
    if (inFile.fail())
        return 0;
    NewByte = ENCRYPTION_FORMULA;
    outFile.put(NewByte);
}

inFile.close();     
outFile.close();    

return 1; 
}


int Decrypt (char * FILENAME, char * NEW_FILENAME)
{
std::ifstream inFile;
std::ofstream outFile;
char Byte;
inFile.open(FILENAME, ios::in | ios::binary);
outFile.open(NEW_FILENAME, ios::out | ios::binary);

while(!inFile.eof())
{
    char NewByte;
    Byte = inFile.get();
    if (inFile.fail())
        return 0;
    NewByte = DECRYPTION_FORMULA;
    outFile.put(NewByte);
}

inFile.close();
outFile.close();

return 1;
}


    int main()
    {

char EncFile[200];      
char NewEncFile[200];   
char DecFile[200];      
char NewDecFile[200];   
int Choice;         
cout << "NOTE: You must encrypt the file with the same file extension!"<<endl;
cout << "Enter 1 to Encrypt / 2 to Decrypt"<<endl;
cin >> Choice;  

switch(Choice)
{
case 1:
    cout << "Enter the current Filename:    ";
    cin >> EncFile; 
    cout << "Enter the new Filename:    ";
    cin >> NewEncFile;  
    Encrypt(EncFile, NewEncFile);   
    break;

case 2: 
    cout << "Enter the current Filename:    ";
    cin >> DecFile;
    cout << "Enter the new Filename:    ";
    cin >> NewDecFile;
    Decrypt(DecFile, NewDecFile);   
    break;
}


return 0;   //Exit!
```

}

Comment: Are you using WinRT or pure C WinAPI? WinRT makes this *much* easier but only works on more modern Windows systems.

Comment: How is the code shown here relevant to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'open file' dialog you're refering to is a part of the Windows API. To add it you'd have to write a bunch of code and it's probably not worth it for the task at hand. If you want to do it anyway, read more about it on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: It's not that hard, actually. The hardest bit is to know that you need the HWND from `GetConsoleWindow`.

Comment: Thanks for that, a very helpful answer. Do you know of any tutorials that show how to implement this, to some extent? or examples of code that show how others have implemented this in the past?

Comment: The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381399(v=vs.85).aspx) contains some simple tutorials, for more advanced stuff I'd recommend you look for some books (Programming Windows, etc).